# How disable element list with a condition on angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, list, angularjs-ng-disabled

I need to disable element list inside a nav when certain parameter is equal to 'N', and enable it when it is equal to 'S'. This is my code

```
<div class="slidebar-nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <div class="side-menu-container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-disabled="trxAbil.I9WSFONI == 'N'" 
            ng-class="{'current' : itemSelected === 'Gestione fondi'}"
            ui-sref="home.pag1.inquiryFondi({innescatoDaMenuLaterale: true})" 
            ng-click="onMenuSelection('Gestione fondi')">
          <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Gestione fondi</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active" 
            ng-class="{'current' : itemSelected === 'Invio fondi'}"
            ui-sref="home.pag2" ng-click="onMenuSelection('Invio fondi')">
          <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Invio fondi</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active" 
            ng-class="{'current' : itemSelected === 'Sintesi fondi'}" 
            ui-sref="home.pag3" ng-click="onMenuSelection('Sintesi fondi')">
          <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Sintesi fondi</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I try with `ng-disabled="trxAbil.I9WSFONI == 'N'"` but it doesn't work.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: why you want to make `<li>` disabled. See if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083400/angularjs-ng-disabled-not-working-with-list-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're using Bootstrap in your UI (by watching `navbar navbar-default` classes).

You simply need to assign `disabled` class based on your conditions to disable an item in the menu. It will automatically prevent the click on that item.

```
<li ng-class="{'current' : itemSelected === 'Gestione fondi', 'disabled': trxAbil.I9WSFONI == 'N'}" ... > ... </li>
```

No need to assign `ng-disabled` to the `li` element.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Only another question: if I wanted the conditions to be respected were two? Can I write this ng-class={ 'disabled': (trxAbil.I9WSFONI == 'N' && trxAbil.I9WSFONA == 'N')} ?

Comment: @Lorenzo -- Yes, you can write unlimited conditions, provided that the expression will return valid boolean value ultimately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the item but make it not clickable and look disabled using  CSS or your are using bootstrap then add `'disabled' : trxAbil.I9WSFONI == 'N'` condition `ng-class` attribute in `<li>` tag:

**CSS:**

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
    opacity:0.6;         //This grays it out to look disabled
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-class="{'disabled' : trxAbil.I9WSFONI == 'N', 'current' : itemSelected === 'Gestione fondi'}"   ui-sref="home.pag1.inquiryFondi({innescatoDaMenuLaterale: true})" ng-click="onMenuSelection('Gestione fondi')"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Gestione fondi</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you too, but the css is not necessary.

Comment: Yes css not require if you are using bootstrap library.